# How to select the Google search bar using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, css-selectors

I'm using the Chrome extension "Shortkeys" to write shortcut-executable Javascript code that selects the Google search bar while browsing Google searches. Important: I'm not trying to select Chrome's address bar, but the actual search bar on Google's website. I found the search bar element using "inspect element" and found it was inside a div with class "a4bIc". The first tag of the search bar element is "input". So my code is this:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("div.a4bIc input")[document.selectedResultId]
```

Except it doesn't select the search bar. What am I missing?

Comment: What is this `document.selectedResultId` equal to?

Comment: Try it with `document.getElementsByClassName("gLFyf gsfi")[0];` it will return you the input element. You can access the value of the input element with `value` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three suggestions:

1. Looking at the way the google search HTML is structured it looks like you would be better off using the 'name' property in order to reliably select the search input. The selector you want to use is `[name='q']`
2. [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) object. If I'm not mistaken then you cannot access a member of a `NodeList` using an ID (This is in contrast with the very similar `HTMLCollection` object. Don't worry, if it seems confusing, it's because it is!). For a simple lookup like this I suggest using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which will simply return the first selected node directly.
3. Depending upon what you want to do with the google search bar it seems you will need to do some kind of combination of `.focus()` and `.click()`. In my test just now I was only able to get the dropdown of suggestions to appear by firing focus and then click after.

Putting all three of these together:

```
function openGoogleSearchUI(){
  let searchInput = document.querySelector("[name='q']");
  searchInput.focus();
  searchInput.click();
}
```

Naturally you can adapt what you do with the input as you see fit, or just use the `document.querySelector` line to get the input element directly.

Caveat Emptor: I can only see that this works on the Google search UI that I received just now, in the UK, on desktop Chrome. No guarantees that it will work the same in the future or from a different device, as Google can change the structure of the code as they see fit at any time.

Comment: It works! Thank you. I replaced searchInput.click() with searchInput.select() to highlight the text for easy replacement